# Decode Result From JSON-RPC eth_call to a Smart Contract

Tags: python, byte, ethereum, json-rpc, web3py

I would like to know if web3py or another package has a function to decode the result you get when you send a call to a smart contract.
Something similar to `decode_function_input` or `abi.decodeParameters`.
I know that doing `contract.functions.myFunc().call()` will return the value as expected but I need to do HTTP request, sending to Infura the JSON-RPC object.
Doing
`response.json()` I get a json object

```
{
 'jsonrpc': '2.0',
 'id': 1,
 'result': *some string representing bytes*
}
```

How can I transform this result field to get the same thing as what I get when running `contract.functions.myFunc().call()`?

Searched stackoverflow but only found answer on how to decode inputs but not outputs.

Also tried to look at the code of web3py to understand how the decoding is done there, but got lost in the hundreds of functions and the different web3._utils.abi and eth_utils.abi, etc... files.

Comment: I am not a subject matter expert here, but it might be helpful to edit your question to explicitly include "the value as expected" that you mention is returned by `contract.functions.myFunc().call()`.